# NOAA forecast gloabal marine web data

Tags: web-services, weather, noaa

is there any way to get gloabal marine forecast data from NOAA website to use it into an android application?
For marine data i mean tides, wind speed and direction, temperature.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [here](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices)? For example, API v2 provide Search and access datasets and station and/or location data. Let me now.

Comment: Hi. I've seen, but this provide weather data for entire world? I'm interest to weather data for Europe